# BizTalk What does mean segment and progress from "Exception thrown from: segment X progress Y" communicate

Tags: exception, biztalk, tracking, biztalk-2010

What does 'segment' and 'progress' mean in that kind of exception

> 2)  xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'MainEventProcess.MainEvent(5b530a24-7336-4695-78ee-1d4ffdd9f210)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
>   If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: cf584087-a9d3-4be7-8da7-eae49fd4a108
>   Shape name: SendDeviationOut
>   ShapeId: dc5c3484-7955-4d75-b1f9-7e0ca8ecbc1e
>   Exception thrown from: **segment 4**, **progress 8**
>   Inner exception: Exception occurred when persisting state to the database.

Full details hereon MSDN:
[Exception during execution of Orchestration](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b24b832-fa2a-4c6a-b01a-c3207998672c/exception-during-execution-of-orchestration?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Can it be helpful in searching errors in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's nothing you need to worry about and is not related to your app/code/implementation.

The two items you need to act on are **SendDeviationOut** and **Exception occurred when persisting state to the database**.  You are most likely publishing a message and there are no Subscribers.  This is the "no Subscribers found" error from the Orchestration engine.

Now, to answer your specific question, those are markers to blocks of C# code that XLang compiler generated from your Orchestration.  Basically, every statement is organized into a group, segment, and each is executed and tracked individually, progress.  If you open the File0.cs, you will see this in action.